# DevExpress для XE

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe

Всем привет! У меня возник вопрос к тем, кто работал на линейке делфи XE. В частности интересует такой набор компонентов, как DevExpress. Кто пробовал его устанавливать? Стоит или не стоит поднимать на них проекты? Акцентирую на XE именно, а не XE5 или Delphi 7  каком-нибудь. Спасибо заранее всем за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ссылке ниже можно скачать триал-версию линейки продуктов для VCL, в триал также входит месяц бесплатного использования тех.поддержки DevExpress. Советую именно с качеством тех.поддержки ознакомиться в первую очередь, т.к. у DevExpress тех.поддержка впринципе одна из лучших, все вопросы отвечаются в первые же сутки.

https://go.devexpress.com/DevExpressDownload_VCLTrial.aspx

Comment: Единственный минус - это цена и если нужна будет доработка софта в будущем, то нужно будет опять платить, ведь лицензия на год.

Answer (score 1):

Мы используем в своих проектах именно на XE. Вполне устраивает функционал, недоработок совсем немного, и всё при желании несложно правится, и главное саппорт всегда активно отвечает на все вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress использовать стОит!

Comment: Содержательность ответа зашкаливает))) удивляюсь кто еще очки вам накинул за него), особенно на фоне моего вполне нормального вопроса, который решили заминусить).